# what does O(n) means in c#

Tags: c#, operation

I'm learning c# and on many MSDN pages related to c# I came across the terms like O(n) log of O(n). for e.g.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.trimtosize.aspx

in Remarks there is statement as" This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count."

My Query -> I want to know what does general meaning of O(n) operation here, and what are the resources to know more about this notation?

Comment: Link is broken. Can you check?

Comment: O(n) is not a C# term. It means that method will take 'linear time'. i.e., it grows 1:1 with the size of the input.

Comment: @OzanGunceler chk link now ,edited